# Customize the "standard" Page List Gadget on Blogger

Tags: css

how can I remove the highlight effect on the menu tab that I´m on, but still have  a mouse-over effect on the items?

Comment: Can you please show your code so that we can help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the hover CSS selector 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Not sure how you have your menu set up but here is an example.

```
.manu-nav a:hover { 
    color: tomato;
}

.menu-nav li:hover { 
    background-color: gray;
}
```

As for removing the current effect of the active, you want to look at how the page you are trying to change is set up.  There is probably a class or an id added to that highlighted element (something like "active").  That class or ID will have some styling associated with it.  When you move to another page in the menu, you should notice that the ID or Class (i.e. active) moved to that new tab.

Hope this helps.